# Social Menu Icon issue - no hyperlink when adding class

Tags: css, menu, icons, wordpress-theming, font-awesome

I'm using my own infinity news child theme on littleseabear.com. infinity news uses ion icons and for the icon to appear in the social menu the css goes something like:

```
social-icons ul a[href*="website.com/"]:after{
content: \f236}
```

issue is that ion icons doesn't have a goodreads icon. I currently set the icon as a book, but would like to have the goodreads logo.
I tried adding  fa-brands fa-goodreads (fontawesome classes) to the menu, it gives me the correct image, removes the hyperlink. menu-image plugin does the same.

So I think I need to add it to the theme fonts but can't figure out how to do that.

I would even be happy to remove ion icons with fontawesome if I could get the hyperlink to work if having both would cause a conflict.

The instructions are confusing me (dyslexia is probably not helping) and can’t find a video.

Can someone help give me an easy, breakdown step-by-step?

I have left an example of what happens if I add a class to the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcomplicated this for myself and all I had to do was change the font family used.